# Why does this JavaScript object have no values? And why does it not throw an error?

Tags: javascript, syntax-error, javascript-objects

I was trying to make a pannable web page and I came across this code:

```
const renderer = ({ minScale, maxScale, element, scaleSensitivity = 10 }) => {
    const state = {
        element,
        minScale,
        maxScale,
        scaleSensitivity,
        transformation: {
            originX: 0,
            originY: 0,
            translateX: 0,
            translateY: 0,
            scale: 1
        },
    };
    return Object.assign({}, makeZoom(state), makePan(state));
};
```

(link to GitHub repository: https://github.com/kwdowik/zoom-pan)

I do not understand what the const state is, it looks like an object without values.
In the google developer tools console, I tried running this code:

`const state = {1, 2, 3, 4};`

As expected, I got this error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number", which makes sense because the const state is neither an array nor an object. My question is, how come it does not error out when defined inside the renderer function?

Comment: Please read the ES6 docs on Object destructuring.

Comment: @collab-with-tushar-raj Note that this isn't object destructuring (that's for unpacking object properties and assigning them to variables), the syntax they're asking about is [shorthand property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#property_definitions)